# model logistic growth for two different bacteria over time

Tags: logistic, model, growth-model

I have thw following data representing the number of bacteria detected in wastewater.
I would to model the growth overtime. Here is the data

```r
structure(list(ID = 0:88, A = c(1610000, 7110000, 5530000, 8220000, 
10800000, 335000, 350000, 847000, 342000, 286000, 330000, 1300000, 
1330000, 1360000, 3020000, 3330000, 887000, 1310000, 434000, 
1140000, 698000, 178000, 467000, 940000, 632000, 902000, 228000, 
224000, 678000, 304000, 322000, 147000, 259000, 103000, 127000, 
83100, 130000, 119000, 22600, 518000, 430000, 1170000, 432000, 
312000, 506000, 482000, 442000, 123000, 851000, 327000, 279000, 
356000, 280000, 375000, 283000, 596000, 99000, 1020000, 1750000, 
1810000, 6450000, 8820000, 8060000, 15900000, 8060000, 7310000, 
4310000, 6840000, 3890000, 4250000, 1710000, 696000, 1160000, 
2320000, 2260000, 1800000, 1460000, 1460000, 977000, 1260000, 
1330000, 1260000, 39400, 225000, 660000, 248000, 78400, 1730000, 
2540000), B = c(105000, 1220000, 266000, 863000, 1630000, 520000, 
932000, 975000, 195000, 76400, 222000, 342000, 2460000, 8160000, 
6490000, 524000, 471000, 660000, 552000, 1e+06, 327000, 626000, 
139000, 220000, 92500, 23600, 164000, 16500, 2720, 12200, 12600, 
4880, 32600, 1, 1650, 15700, 113000, 1, 4100, 169000, 219000, 
104000, 89700, 56100, 38100, 102000, 44400, 1000, 1000, 1000, 
45600, 114000, 71600, 31100, 423000, 279000, 88800, 375000, 277000, 
110000, 759000, 1780000, 806000, 2910000, 1770000, 1650000, 1440000, 
2920000, 1610000, 297000, 88800, 111000, 51800, 546000, 189000, 
231000, 55300, 13600, 108000, 170000, 150000, 36700, 1000, 31000, 
131000, 61800, 17600, 34000, 51400)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-89L))
```

It looks like this

```r
> df
   ID        A       B
1   0  1610000  105000
2   1  7110000 1220000
3   2  5530000  266000
4   3  8220000  863000
5   4 10800000 1630000
6   5   335000  520000
7   6   350000  932000
```

I´m trying logistic growth as follows:

```r
model = nls(A ~ SSlogis(ID, a, b, c), data = df)
plot(df$ID, df$A)
lines(df$ID, predict(model))
```

[image]

Can you help me on modeling both A and B. A and B are two different bacterial growth, the main idea is to see what difference there is between both.